# Explanation of VBA code needed

Tags: vba, excel

I don't really understand this VBA code, what is the meaning of "find" in this statement, can anyone help me to understand?

```
rngOutput = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(p_objReportActual.Reportname) _
            .Range(Range("A2"), Range("A2").End(xlToRight)).Offset(-1, 0) _
            .Find(objEachAnalysis.Analysis, , , xlWhole).Offset(2, 0)
```

Comment: Please read the documentation of the [`Find` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx) of a `Range` object.

Answer (score 0):

Write `debug.print objEachAnalysis.Analysis` before the code.

The code would set the rngOutput two rows lower than the found value, printed on the console (Immediate Window).

After the code write `debug.print rngOutput.address` to see the address on the same Immediate Window.

To see the Immediate Window, press `ctrl+G` once you are in the Visual Basic Editor in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

The expression may look quite complex at first sight, you can split it to make things more straightforward, here is the example with comments:

```
    ' get target sheet name
    sTargetSheet = p_objReportActual.Reportname
    ' get the value which need to be found
    vToFind = objEachAnalysis.Analysis
    ' get the sheet object
    Set oSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(sTargetSheet)
    ' get actually all cells within row 2 as init range
    Set oInitRange = oSheet.Range(Range("A2"), Range("A2").End(xlToRight))
    ' get the range to search in as init range shifted by 1 row up
    Set oSearchRange = oInitRange.Offset(-1, 0)
    ' get the first cell where the value found
    Set oFoundCell = oSearchRange.Find(vToFind, , , xlWhole)
    ' get result cell shifted by 2 row down
    Set oResultCell = oFoundCell.Offset(2, 0)
    ' show the cell on the sheet
    oResultRange.Select
```

Now it's obvious that `.Find()` is just a method of range object, you can easily find the help topic on MSDN for this method as pointed in comments.

Comment: how does this help the user answer his question?

Answer (score 0):

rngOutput is the cell 2 rows below where the value of 'objEachAnalysis.Analysis' is found in the range A2 to the last cell to the right in a contiguous range in the worksheet 'p_objReportActual.Reportname' and 1 row above

So if there is data in A2:Z2, the function looks in the range A2:Z1 for an exact match to objEachAnalysis.Analysis. Say it's found in C1, then the rngOutput is two cells down. i.e. it returns C3